# Custom Application Class in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I had to create custom class that extends Application class. I created class, add instance of Application class, create additional constructors, add Application Attribute in the top of the class. After that when I test application on android device it crashes immediately. There is no error message just this show up in output console:

**Part of Output console message:**

> [art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128] JNI ERROR (app(_ZN3art8CheckJNI16CallObjectMethodEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDz+160)
>   [art] art/runtime/runtime.cc:404]   native: #13 pc 000000000000a640 
>   /data/app/pl.esticrm.MyApp-1/lib/arm64/libmonodroid.so
>   (java_interop_jnienv_call_object_method+36) [art]
>   art/runtime/runtime.cc:404]   native: #14 pc 00000000000b9e10   (???)
>   [art] art/runtime/runtime.cc:404]   at
>   md51e2b575927e2fc0f467b22123a11ceb7.MyAppCustomClass.n_onCreate(Native
>   method) [art] art/runtime/runtime.cc:404]   at
>   md51e2b575927e2fc0f467b22123a11ceb7.MyAppCustomClass.onCreate(MyAppCustomClass.java:25)
>   [art] art/runtime/runtime.cc:404]   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1032)
>   ... [libc] Fatal signal 6
>   (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 16574 (icrm.MyApp)

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="pl.app.MyApp">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="MyApp" />
</manifest>
```

**MyAppCustomClass.cs**

```
namespace MyApp.Droid.Applications
{

    [Application(Debuggable = true, Theme = "@style/AppTheme", Icon = "@drawable/ic_launcher", Label = "MyApp")]
    public class MyAppCustomClass : Application
    {
        public MyAppCustomClass()
        {
        }

        protected MyAppCustomClass(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
        {
        }

        public readonly string[] permissions = { Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage, Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage };

        public NativeActions native = new NativeActions();
        public AndroidActions actions = new AndroidActions();

        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();
            System.Console.WriteLine("Custom Class test");
        }
    }
}
```

I just looked at stackoverflow and xamarin forum questions and nothing would fits to my problem.

Comment: Remember to call `base.OnCreate()`.

Comment: @Cheesebaron I added it and it doesn't change anything, I also updated post to be more precise

Comment: Did I read correctly that you are creating an instance of the Application class and by that you mean you are doing something like `new MyAppCustomClass()`?

Comment: When I comment out the 2 lines with NativeActions and AndroidActions, it works all right. So I think the problem is with these 2 packages. Please check the usage of the packages of NativeActions and AndroidActions.

Comment: @AbbyWang-MSFT Thank you, I didn't think that this packages would make any difference. It works right now.

Comment: @KonradUciechowski Do yo mean you have solved the problem now?

Comment: @AbbyWang-MSFT Yes, I added this two packages but it wasn't necessary to put it there. Thank you!

Comment: I created a simple xamarin.android project and added your code to my project(The only difference is I comment out he 2 lines with NativeActions and AndroidActions). But I did not get the JNI ERROR messages as yours. By the way, I changed the target version from 28 to 27. I suggest you delete the obj and bin folders and then rebuild the project.

Comment: You can also refer to this:  https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=6696